# Analysis of Redis error logs "LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory" and more

Tags: caching, redis, devops

I am frequently seeing these messages in the `redis` logs

**1#**

```
602854:M 23 Dec 2022 09:48:54.028 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
602854:M 23 Dec 2022 09:48:54.035 * Background saving started by pid 3266364
3266364:C 23 Dec 2022 09:48:55.844 * DB saved on disk
3266364:C 23 Dec 2022 09:48:55.852 * RDB: 12 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
602854:M 23 Dec 2022 09:48:55.938 * Background saving terminated with success
```

**2#**

```
LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory
```

**3#**

```
7678:signal-handler (1671738516) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.300 # User requested shutdown...
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.300 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.300 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.300 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.720 * DB saved on disk
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.720 * Removing the pid file.
7678:M 22 Dec 2022 23:48:36.720 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
7901:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # WARNING supervised by systemd - you MUST set appropriate values for TimeoutStartSec and TimeoutStopSec in your service unit.
7901:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
7914:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
7914:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # Redis version=6.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=7914, just started
7914:C 22 Dec 2022 23:48:37.071 # Configuration loaded
```

Are these messages concerning?
Let me know if there's any optimization to be carried out in terms of settings.

Comment: Do you have a master-replica setup? Are you seeing these logs in master node or replica node?

Comment: @AnkitSahay Nope. But I have two instances of Redis running on the same server.

Comment: Ok. So are those two instances running as 2 different masters? Or is the second instance a replica of the 1st instance?

Comment: Yeah, those two are running as different masters.

Answer (score 3):

The first set of informational messages is related to Redis persistence: it appears your Redis node is configured to save the database to disk if 300 seconds elapsed and it surpassed 10 write operations against it. You can change [that](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#L417) according to your needs through the Redis configuration file.

The message `LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory`, on the other side, is an error message received while attempting to connect to a Redis instance which is loading its dataset in memory: that occurs during the startup for standalone servers and master nodes or when replicas reconnect and fully resynchronize with master. If you are seeing this error too often and not right after a system restart, I would suggest to check your system log files and learn why your Redis instance is restarting or resynchronizing (depending on your topology).